# What is the correct way in Vim to autocommand ":highlight" after a buffer is loaded?

Tags: vim, autocmd, autocommand

Due to various reasons, I run Vim at sixteen-colors, synced w/ my terminal's colors. In a recent Vim update, I've had to rework my "~/.vimrc" completely to get it back into running order on Linux.

Initially I was shocked to find that this simple line did not work (even w/ "syntax on" preceding it):

```
:highlight Comment ctermfg=White
```

I'm also using a "LineNr" ctermfg. No matter where I placed/stacked the "Comment" ctermfg, it didn't work, or interfered w/ everything else sourcing correctly (ie, placed in the same line w/ "LineNr"). However, I found that calling "Comment" after a buffer had loaded would make the comments appear as intended.

I am new to autocmd in Vim (and want to know how it works, anyways). Is there an "autocmd" call that I can have in my "~/.vimrc" that will run the aforementioned line of code immediately after a buffer has loaded?

I have tried several iterations (BufWritePre, BufWritePost, etc.) and been unsuccessful. This was my previous attempt:

```
autocmd BufWinPost * :highlight Comment ctermfg=white
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't resort to `:autocmd` without reason; search harder for the root cause!

Your description lacks specifics; I guess your chosen colorscheme (or a plugin, but no sane plugin should interfere with the default highlightings) overrides your custom one for `Comment`. You can check who defined this via

```
:verbose highlight Comment
```

If this points to your colorscheme, you simply need to execute your `:highlight` command *after* it. For this, you need to understand `:help initialization`, and maybe check the output of `:scriptnames`. If you have a `:colorscheme foo` command in your `~/.vimrc`, it *should* be as simple as putting the `:highlight` command after it.

You do need an `:autocmd` if you switch colorschemes on the fly, as most colorschemes override the basic `Comment` definition. The correct event and pattern for that would be `ColorScheme *`

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm not running a "colorscheme" command. As stated, I have simply synced vim up to my terminal's sixteen-color palette and manipulated Vim's syntax from there whether manually thru "~/.vimrc" or otherwise.

However, your instruction to utilize ":verbose" solved the problem. Somehow the "syntax.vim" file's "ctermfg" file was changed to colors that I didn't want. Thx!

Comment: "syncolor.vim," not "syntax.vim". My apologies.

Comment: Ah, great you've figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

If I do a quick `:h autocmd-events`, I find the the event `BufWinPost` does not exist. I think, you want `BufWinEnter` instead. The autocmd you wrote should work, except for the `:`. HTH